# How can combine 3 matrices into 1 matrice with reversible-approach?

Tags: python, numpy, dataframe, reshape, reversing

I want to **reshape** my 24x20 matrices `'A'`,`'B'`,`'C'` which are extracted from text file and are saved before and after normalizing by `def normalize()` in for-loop through cycles in such way that each cycles would be a row with all elements of 3 matrices side by side like below:

```
[[A(1,1),B(1,1),C(1,1),A(1,2),B(1,2),C(1,2),...,A(24,20),B(24,20),C(24,20)] #cycle1
 [A(1,1),B(1,1),C(1,1),A(1,2),B(1,2),C(1,2),...,A(24,20),B(24,20),C(24,20)] #cycle2
 [A(1,1),B(1,1),C(1,1),A(1,2),B(1,2),C(1,2),...,A(24,20),B(24,20),C(24,20)]] #cycle3
```

So far based on @odyse suggestion I used following snippet in the end of for-loop:

```
for cycle in range(cycles):
dff = pd.DataFrame({'A_norm':A_norm[cycle] , 'B_norm': B_norm[cycle] , 'C_norm': C_norm[cycle] } , index=[0])
D = dff.as_matrix().ravel()
if cycle == 0:
    Results = np.array(D)
else:
    Results = np.vstack((Results, D2))
np.savetxt("Results.csv", Results, delimiter=",")
```

but there is a problem when I use after `def normalize()` in for-loop in spite of its error (ValueError) it also has `warning FutureWarning: Method .as_matrix will be removed in a future version. Use .values instead` for `D = dff.as_matrix().ravel()` which is not important but right now since it is FutureWarning nevertheless I checked the shape of output was correct for 3 cycles by using `print(data1.shape)` and it was **(3, 1440)** which is 3 rows as 3 cycles and number of columns should be 3 times 480= 1440 but all in all wasn't **stable** solution.

the complete scripts are following:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import os

def normalize(value, min_value, max_value, min_norm, max_norm):
    new_value = ((max_norm - min_norm)*((value - min_value)/(max_value - min_value))) + min_norm
    return new_value

#the size of matrices are (24,20)
df1 = np.zeros((24,20))
df2 = np.zeros((24,20))
df3 = np.zeros((24,20))


#next iteration create all plots, change the number of cycles
cycles = int(len(df)/480)
print(cycles)
for cycle in range(3):
    count =  '{:04}'.format(cycle)
    j = cycle * 480
    new_value1 = df['A'].iloc[j:j+480]
    new_value2 = df['B'].iloc[j:j+480]
    new_value3 = df['C'].iloc[j:j+480]
    df1 = print_df(mkdf(new_value1))
    df2 = print_df(mkdf(new_value2))
    df3 = print_df(mkdf(new_value3))              
    for i in df:
        try:
            os.mkdir(i)
        except:
            pass
        min_val = df[i].min()
        min_nor = -1
        max_val = df[i].max()
        max_nor = 1
        ordered_data = mkdf(df.iloc[j:j+480][i])
        csv = print_df(ordered_data)
        #Print .csv files contains matrix of each parameters by name of cycles respectively
        csv.to_csv(f'{i}/{i}{count}.csv', header=None, index=None)            
        if 'C' in i:
            min_nor = -40
            max_nor = 150
            #Applying normalization for C between [-40,+150]
            new_value3 = normalize(df['C'].iloc[j:j+480], min_val, max_val, -40, 150)
            C_norm = print_df(mkdf(new_value3))
            C_norm.to_csv(f'{i}/norm{i}{count}.csv', header=None, index=None)  
        else:
            #Applying normalization for A,B between    [-1,+1]
            new_value1 = normalize(df['A'].iloc[j:j+480], min_val, max_val, -1, 1)
            new_value2 = normalize(df['B'].iloc[j:j+480], min_val, max_val, -1, 1)
            A_norm = print_df(mkdf(new_value1))
            B_norm = print_df(mkdf(new_value2))
            A_norm.to_csv(f'{i}/norm{i}{count}.csv', header=None, index=None) 
            B_norm.to_csv(f'{i}/norm{i}{count}.csv', header=None, index=None)
    dff = pd.DataFrame({'A_norm':A_norm[cycle] , 'B_norm': B_norm[cycle] , 'C_norm': C_norm[cycle] } , index=[0])
    D = dff.as_matrix().ravel()
    if cycle == 0:
        Results = np.array(D)
    else:
        Results = np.vstack((Results, D))
    np.savetxt("Results.csv", Results , delimiter=',', encoding='utf-8')
#Check output shape whether is (3, 1440) or not 
data1 = np.loadtxt('Results.csv', delimiter=',')
print(data1.shape)
```

**Note1:** my data is txt file is following:

```
id_set: 000
     A: -2.46882615679
     B: -2.26408246559
     C: -325.004619528
```

**Note2:**  I provided a dataset in text file for 3 cycles:
[Text dataset](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1oTf-2QDLo-n3UUTyY92h4zH8kffR0KAm/view?usp=sharing)

**Note3:** for mapping A, B, C parameters into matrices in right order I used `print_df()` `mkdf()` functions but I didn't mention due to reduce it to the core problem and just leave a minimal example in start of this post. Let me know if you need that.

**Expected result** should be done by completing **for-loop** on `'A_norm'`,`'B_norm'`,`'C_norm'` which are represented normalized versions of `'A'`,`'B'`,`'C'` respectively and output let's call it "Results.csv" should be **reversible** to regenerate `'A'`,`'B'`,`'C'` matrices through cycles again save them in csv. files for controlling , therefore if you have any ideas about reverse part please mention that separately otherwise just control it by using `print(data.shape)` and it should be **(3, 1440)**. 
Have a nice day and thanks in advance!