# How can display differences of two matrices by subtraction via heatmap in python?

Tags: python, dataframe, matrix, seaborn, heatmap

I have two matrices `[A]`(Expected_matrice) , `[B]`(Predicted_matrice) I need to create the third one `[C]`(Error_matrice) via subtraction of them `[C]=[A]-[B]` and pass it to Pandas dataframe and save in csv file.

Since abovementioned matrices' size are 24*20 and I try to:

First: **Plot** `[C]` via `sns.heatmap(C, cbar=True, cmap="gray_gist")`

Second: **Evaluate** [C] via applying `sum(abs(abs([A])-abs([B])))/24*20` to check that how good it is. In fact I calculating amount of **Error** by that. I also know that it's possible to use another method like MSE `from Sklearn import metrics` by applying:

```
from Sklearn import metrics
print(metrics.mean_squared_error(A,B))
```

Since the elements of matrices are **lists** I've used : `[i - j for (i, j) in zip(A,B)]`

My codes are following:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.ndimage.filters import gaussian_filter

#A,B can be read from .csv files
A = pd.read_csv('D:\A.csv', header=None)
B = pd.read_csv('D:\B.csv', header=None)

#A,B can be assumed as lists
df_A = pd.DataFrame(A)
df_B = pd.DataFrame(B)

#calculate error matrix via subtraction 
C = [i - j for (i, j) in zip(A,B)]

#Pass error matrix to Pandas dataframe
df_C = pd.DataFrame(C)
df_C.to_csv('Error_Matrix.csv', header=None, index=None)

#Evaluation
Eval= sum(abs(abs([A])-abs([B])))/24*20
Eval_ =  '{:04}'.format(Eval)
print(Eval_)

#Plotting C
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2 , figsize=(20,15))

plt.subplot(1,2,1)
ax = sns.heatmap(C, cbar=True, cmap="gist_gray")
plt.title(f'Error Matrix  Error={Eval_}', fontsize=14 , fontweight='bold', color='black', loc='center', style='italic')
plt.axis('off')

plt.subplot(1,2,2)
C_smooth = gaussian_filter(dfr_b, sigma=1)
ax = sns.heatmap(C_smooth, vmin=np.min(C_smooth), vmax=np.max(C_smooth), cmap ="gray" , cbar=True , cbar_kws={"ticks":[0,33,67,100]})
plt.title(f'Error Matrix Smooth  Error={Eval_}', fontsize=14 , fontweight='bold', color='black', loc='center', style='italic')
plt.axis('off')
plt.savefig('Error_Matrix.png') 
plt.show()
```

Expected results:

[image: img]

**Note** white color shows Error=0 and solid black color shows Error=maximum.
Mostly should be error but i don't want to have black result I expected Gray color mostly.

**Data(matrix A,B):** [Matrix A](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1S5h1o0ErABc3-GKJi80ho-RY54N2nl-Q/view?usp=sharing) , [Matrix B](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HEidnQe_g_NypexjgGhIHaSY8ebz8zUL/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Hi Mario, what is actually the question? ...and why do you put a Gaussian filter?

Comment: If I get it right, black is `error = 0`. Moreover, if you scale with `vmin` and `vmax` to the extrema of your array, it will, naturally, range from black to white. Finally, I don't think that `abs( abs(A) - abs(B) )` is a good error indicator; `abs( A - B )` is probably better.

Comment: @mikuszefski The Gaussian filter I've used to cancel redundancy and it highlights the results much better. I'm not sure if we have alternative choices. Regarding formulas which u used **MSE(Mean Square Error)** and **MAPE(Mean Absolute Percentage Error)**  in MAPE it'd be better to use `( deltax) / A`  instead of `( deltax) / B`  in  `ox_ = 100 * np.sum(( 1 - np.abs( ( deltax) / A ) )) / ( len( A ) * len( B[0] ) )` just some few problems are left like keep harmony of colors in numerical description in `colormap` and add `%` to numbers in `colormap` like expected picture in post. I liked pics.

Comment: @mikuszefski I was wondering if you're into DNN and you could help me by look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55986805/how-can-correctly-improve-the-performance-of-rnn-with-or-without-cross-validatio) and check my reshape of my dataset. I feel something is wrong or it hasn't been implemented scientifically. I want to get feedback from your side at least check my approach and dataset please.

Comment: Hi Mario, while an interesting topic I am not into NNs. If I have some spare time I might look into it anyhow, but as your questions seems quite interesting I am sure you'll attract the right guys to answer it. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do something like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


mx = 10 + 3 * np.random.random( 20 * 10 )
mx = mx.reshape( 20, 10 )
nx = 10 + 3 * np.random.random( 20 * 10 )
nx = nx.reshape( 20, 10 )
deltax = mx - nx
ox = 100 * ( 1 - np.abs( ( deltax) / mx ) )

scale = max( [ abs(min( np.concatenate( deltax ) ) ), abs( max( np.concatenate( deltax ) ) ) ] )

chi2 = np.sum( mx - nx )**2
chi2Red = chi2/( len( mx ) * len( mx[0] ) )
print chi2, chi2Red

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot( 2, 2, 1 )
bx = fig.add_subplot( 2, 2, 2 )
cx = fig.add_subplot( 2, 2, 3 )
dx = fig.add_subplot( 2, 2, 4 )

MX1 = ax.matshow( mx, vmin=0, vmax=30 )
MX2 = bx.matshow( nx, vmin=0, vmax=30 )
diffMX = cx.matshow( deltax, cmap='seismic', vmin=-scale, vmax=scale )
errMX = dx.matshow( ox, vmin=0, vmax=100  )
plt.colorbar( MX1, ax=ax )
plt.colorbar( MX2, ax=bx )
plt.colorbar( diffMX, ax=cx )
plt.colorbar( errMX, ax=dx )
plt.show()
```

giving:

```
>> 219.40945851846487 1.0970472925923245
```

[image: test]

I have to say though, that I do not like loosing the information about the sign of deviation. The lower left graph, hence, would be my actual preference. It could be scaled and shifted like the last one such that zero becomes 100% and the data will range from 80% to 120% or somewhat like that.

Comment: actually I like the last one which represents **MAPE** . The dark color shows bad predicts and yellowish colors show better predict. I'm not sure how we can make it vice versa like you mentioned  "It could be scaled and shifted like the last one such that zero becomes 100%" and how we can shift the data from range  from 80% to 120% ?

Comment: @Mario well for the last to be from zero you'd just remove the `1-` in `ox = 100 * ( 1 - np.abs( ( deltax) / mx ) )` leaving `ox = 100 * np.abs( ( deltax ) / mx )` The colormap can always be reversed. Here `viridis` would change to `viridis_r`